# How to modify an element attribute using jQuery or CSS?

Tags: html, css, element

I am trying to change this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.cdn-ec.viddler.com/js/arpeggio/v3/build/main-built.js"></script>

<div class="viddler-auto-embed" data-embed-id="yLDrFKPE4u" data-video-id="b69c8ee1" data-width="380" data-height="285"></div>
```

and change the value of data width to: data-width="450"

I have more than 400 videos on my website and would like to use a shortcut to only change 380 to 450 for the value of data-width.

Would really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first grab the elements dataset and check if 380, then if it is
just grap the element by classname and style width to 450px.

I suspect though that you don't really want to set data-width and data-height, rather, set width and height and then access those directly.

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('viddler-auto-embed')[0].dataset;


if (element.width == 380)
document.getElementsByClassName('viddler-auto-embed')[0].style.width ='450px'
```

```css
.viddler-auto-embed{
border:black solid 2px;
height:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="viddler-auto-embed" data-embed-id="yLDrFKPE4u" data-video-id="b69c8ee1" data-width="380" data-height="285"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

I added the first line you sent + 
.viddler-auto-embed{
data-width:450px;}

but no changes.

Comment: data-width is just an adhoc attribute.  You need to set width.  viddler-auto-embed{ width:450px;  you may also want to set height

Comment: @RezaMirdamadi It may be worth noting that `data-width` is not a valid CSS attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will work, but you can try this:

```js
function widthChanger() {
    let videos = document.querySelectorAll('.viddler-auto-embed');
    let i = 0
    while (i < videos.length - 1) { // loop through all videos
        videos[i].setAttribute("data-width", 450); // changing the data here
    };
};

widthChanger(); // running the function
```

Comment: There is a "Run code snippet" where you can test your answer. I am pretty sure it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it, you can change it by using `data` or `attr` method, which one will work for you depends on how this prop will be read by the plugin. You can try and then choose suitable for you.

```js
//first
$('.viddler-auto-embed').data('width', 450);
console.log(
  'viddler-auto-embed: ',
  $('.viddler-auto-embed').data()
);

//second
$('.viddler-auto-embed1').attr('data-width', 450);
console.log(
  'viddler-auto-embed1: ',
  $('.viddler-auto-embed1').data()
);
```

```css
.viddler-auto-embed {background: #eee;}
.viddler-auto-embed::before {
  content: attr(data-width);
  color: red;
}

.viddler-auto-embed1 {background: #777;}
.viddler-auto-embed1::before {
  content: attr(data-width);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="viddler-auto-embed" data-embed-id="yLDrFKPE4u" data-video-id="b69c8ee1" data-width="380" data-height="285"></div>

<div class="viddler-auto-embed1" data-embed-id="yLDrFKPE4u" data-video-id="b69c8ee1" data-width="380" data-height="285"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change data-height or data-width attribute value whatever you want with jquery.

```js
$(()=> {
let viddler = $('.viddler-auto-embed')
viddler.css({
"width": `${viddler.attr('data-width')}px`,
"height": `${viddler.attr('data-height')}px`
})
})
```

```css
.viddler-auto-embed{
  border: solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="viddler-auto-embed" data-embed-id="yLDrFKPE4u" data-video-id="b69c8ee1" data-width="450" data-height="285"></div>
```